# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, iboutlet

So I'm trying to get the text of an input field in Swift. So here's what I got

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var passwordField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var usernameField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()            
        //Try to log user in by default
        let user = usernameField.text
        let password = passwordField.text
```

It all looks good (I know I didn't close the class, I just pulled it directly out) and when I go to run it, I get

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)

and

[image: You'll have to open the image in a new tab to see it]

(You'll have to open the image in a new tab to see it)

I binded the input fields with the IBOutlet successful, I know that. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem appears to be that usernameField is nil at the point you are trying to access it, and so trying to access .text fails.  I personally find that surprising, since it seems that it should be assigned by the time viewDidLoad is called.  (Unless the fields are not actually in the view).  In any case, use conditional unwrapping to avoid the error.  As a side note, why are you checking the values at the beginning of viewDidLoad?  It seems unlikely that there would be any text in them at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way I think this will work :

```
if let abc = usernameField.text{
        let user = abc

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think You Have to Check This in **TextField's Delegate Method**

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {

}
```

instead ViewDidLoad Or On Action of **ButtonClick**

Cause **TextField Are Empty On ViewDidLoad!**

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem while setting the delegate to a text field. Couldn't figure out was wrong then realized that I had declared the class for a second view controller as a view controller not a UIViewController. I'm new at this.