# Using delegates: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, delegates, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have two `ViewController`s, assume one is named `MainVC` and the other one is named `GetCameraRollImageViewController`. In the second one, there is a `UIScrollView` which holds a `UIImageView`, since I'm using segue to show the second view controller, I've to use its delegate in the `MainVC`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GetTextDelegate, GetCameraRollImageDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate  {
//
//other codes
//
    @IBAction func setNewImageFromCameraRoll(segue:UIStoryboardSegue)    {
        if let newImageVC = segue.sourceViewController as? GetCameraRollImageViewController{

            var scale:CGFloat = 1.0/newImageVC.scrollView.zoomScale;
            var visibleRect:CGRect!
            visibleRect.origin.x = newImageVC.scrollView.contentOffset.x * scale;
            visibleRect.origin.y = newImageVC.scrollView.contentOffset.y * scale;
            visibleRect.size.width = newImageVC.scrollView.bounds.size.width * scale;
            visibleRect.size.height = newImageVC.scrollView.bounds.size.height * scale;
            var cr:CGImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(newImageVC.inputImage.image?.CGImage,visibleRect)
            var cropped:UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: cr)!
            imageView.image = cropped
        }
    }
}
```

The `GetCameraRollImageViewController` code:

```
import UIKit

protocol GetCameraRollImageDelegate{
    //
}

class GetCameraRollImageViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var delegate:GetCameraRollImageDelegate? = nil
    var inputImageDelegate:UIImage!

    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var inputImage:UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5
        self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0
        self.scrollView.contentSize = self.inputImage.frame.size;
        self.scrollView.delegate = self
        inputImage.image = inputImageDelegate
}
    func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return self.inputImage
    }

}
```

But when I trigger `setNewImageFromCameraRoll()` it crashes the app with this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

**Note**: Bothe `scrollView` and `inputImage` are bounded, and I'm not reading them in the `viewDidLoad()`, when they are empty.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701993/fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-value-in-swift)

Comment: @GoZoner it' not duplicated, because 1) I'm not reading in `ViewDidLoad()` 2) i'm using `if ..let`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Updated based on comments]

The line

```
var visibleRect:CGRect!
```

assigns `visibleRect` to `nil` and thus the subsequent line of

```
visibleRect.origin.x = newImageVC.scrollView.contentOffset.x * scale;
```

will then dereference `visibleRect`, find `nil` and produce the exception.  You need to allocate a `CGRect` and assign it to `visibleRect`.

[Original Answer]

Is `visibleRect` bound?  It doesn't look to be.  If that is bound, then you'll notice other uses of `!`...  You need to bind your outlets (typically in InterfaceBuilder):

```
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet var inputImage:UIImageView!
```

Perhaps `scrollView` is not bound and thus, because it is implicitly unwrapped (the `!` operator), when you reference it as `nil` your program will fatal.

Use:

```
var visibleRect = 
  CGRectMake (newImageVC.scrollView.contentOffset.x * scale,
              newImageVC.scrollView.contentOffset.y * scale,
              newImageVC.scrollView.bounds.size.width * scale,
              newImageVC.scrollView.bounds.size.height * scale)
```

Comment: It's bounded in the IB.

Comment: It's a local variable

Comment: `var visibleRect = CGRectMake(...)`.  When you write `var visibleRect:CGRect!` then `visibleRect` is `nil` and _will_ fail.  In your code, you've only declared its type but not allocated any memory for it.

Comment: And you better allocate it before you assign values to it.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% but I believe your problem is that the scrollView has not yet been created. Try passing the image to the new view controller and doing your resizing  in the viewDidLoad of GetCameraRollImageViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a number of problems.

First of all, why do you have an IBAction that takes a segue as a parameter?

Usually what you do is invoke a segue through whatever method, and then implement the preformSegue method. That method gets called whenever a segue is triggered in your view controller.

In performSegue you can get a pointer to the destination view controller and pass parameters to it.

It isn't clear to me how your setNewImageFromCameraRoll method is being called, or how it gets a segue object. It also doesn't make sense to me that you're using the **source** view controller from the segue. I suspect the method doesn't work as you expected.

The next problem has to do with what you're trying to do with the view controller you get from the segue. You're trying to manipulate it's views directly. Don't do that. You should treat a view controller's views as private. Instead you should add properties to your view controller that expose the information you need, and reference those properties.

Messing around with another view controller's views violates the principle of encapsulation. It also frequently fails because the other view controller's views don't get created until it's displayed on-screen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's your first question [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them). And for the second question, I don't manipulate that view directly, i'm just reading some values.

Comment: Oh, an unwind segue! Ok, that explains it. I haven't used them much.

Comment: Reading values is just as bad as writing values, and also likely to fail. You should treat another view controller's views as private, and add properties to expose the information the the VC's public interface.

Answer (score 0):

According to me you haven't connected delegate of V2 class to self in MainVC
"newImageVC?.delegate=self"